# Mysql select one more row for each group

Tags: mysql

Hi there is an exemple of the result that i want

[image: Result that i want]

no : order number 
dataType : 
1 = the number of piece done for a specific week 
           2 = the number of piece remaining 
done : number of piece done
total : number of piece

I would like to make a single query. The first part of this query would return me all the rows with a dataType 1 and the other part would return me all rows with dataType 2. The dataType 2 would be there only once per orders, it is only there to show what is remaining to do.

I have done this query by duplicating my big select and using a UNION, but there is a way to use all the order number returned in the first query to get what is remaining to do for each order by adding a new row.

thank you I hope my question is clear

I have made an sqlfiddle to show you the query that i did

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26a9d/15

```
SELECT 
    no,
    SUM(vCountDone) done,
    (SELECT SUM(vCountTotal) FROM table1) total,
    week,
    '1' AS dataType
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY DATE(week) 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    no,
    SUM(vCountTotal) - SUM(vCountDone) done,
    (SELECT SUM(vCountTotal) FROM table1) total,
    MAX(week),
    '2' AS dataType
FROM
    table1 t2
```

Comment: And your query is? And we can easily start to test it? Why? You provide table definitions, Source test data as inserts into the tables, Your query and a list of expected output so we know, that the query we fixed for you, works with your data :) What do you actually  provide? What do I need to do, based on the actual information in your question, to get test tables setup and loaded with data, and run the query you provide to find out why ift doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Yeah a schema, some test data and a query you've already tried but didn't produce your ideal results would be great in this situation if you can provide them.

Comment: i have added the query that i have created, but i have removed all my conditions and my inner joint... well it is something like that.  Well there is a way that i can use the result of my first query to know for wich order that i need to get the remaining piece. Because now i need to do the same query that i did to get wich order that was returned and add one more condition. (sorry for my english :/) @RyanVincent

Comment: see my update i have made an sqlfiddle thank you @RyanVincent

Comment: Why does the first query use `SUM(vCountDone)` but the second query uses `SUM(vCountTotal) - SUM(vCountDone)`? Are they supposed to be different?

Comment: because i want to have what is remaining to do for that order in one row

Comment: In that case I don't think there's any way to combine them into a single query. If they were the same you could use `GROUP BY DATE(week) WITH ROLLUP` to add a total row.

Comment: i will edit my sqlfiddle and i will try if thw WITH ROLLUP works let me 5 minutes thank

Comment: i'm not able to run the script on sqlfidle but check this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b09c8 .. would i be able to create this result with `WITH ROLLUP` @Barmar

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, there's no query in that fiddle.

Comment: sorry... well i don't know why it doesn't work...  But for each order if i want to have the remaining piece would i be able to do it with `WITH ROLLUP` ... well i will try it in my real query... do you think that there is another way to do it?  @Barmar

Comment: You can't do that with `ROLLUP`. It creates subtotals from the existing aggregation functions, it can't do a different sum.

Comment: @Barmar ok i understand thank you.. well i have to do it like i did?

Comment: Your method looks fine to me.